# Other places to ground oneself without exposed case metal?

Tags: static-discharge, esd

In a computer case, if all portions of (easily accessible) case metal are painted, without having an ESD wriststrap, where else can can one touch to ground themselves to the case?

If I put my tongue on the heatsink, would that perchance do the trick?

Comment: Seeing the heatsinks I have seen... ewww

Comment: Simply said you can't and touching the metal in a case isn't actually grounding yourself but it's better then nothing

Answer (score 0):

Grounding should be:

- Housing of optical drives
- Screws of mainboard mounting/ drives/ case
- Screws/ Housing of the PSU
- PCI Slot covers

I am right sure, the heatsinks are not grounded!

Comment: I would not trust screws...most are aluminum.  One really should use an electrical ground with a proper wrist strap and anti-static matt.

Comment: Aluminum is very conductive.  Most public power lines are aluminum.